# regex_match in CodeIgniter form_validation generates: Message: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I've been looking in other similar posts and the problem seemed to be an unescaped slash. However I'm escaping them.

This is how the string should look:

**23/12/2012**

and this is how I'm declaring the validation rule:

```
regex_match[/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$/]
```

The ending delimiter is there, and the two inbetween slashes for the date are being escaped with a backslash. I've also tried this which is slightly different, but I get the same error:

```
regex_match[/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)\d\d$/]
```

Where's the error?

**EDIT:**

Following your advice, I've tried using a callback function. This is the declaration, which is located within the controller class in which the form validation is being executed:

```
function mach_date($date) {
   /* DEBUG */ echo 'Here I am!'; exit; // execution should stop here displaying the echo
   return (bool)preg_match('/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)\d\d$/', $date);
}
```

Validation rules in **application/config/form_validation.php**:

```
$config = array(
     // other validation groups.....,
     'articles' => array(
          // other validated fields.....,
          array(
                'field' => 'date_p',
                'label' => 'Publishing date',
                'rules' => 'callback_match_date'
          )
     )
);
```

Comment: can you post some more of the problem code itself

Comment: @JulienMay I've added more information of the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set the validation rules you separate them with a | so the |'s in your regex is causing the validation rule to split at those and that is causing the error. Discussion [here](https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/220094/form-validation-regex_match) on the issue. It seems it's a limitation or bug in codeigniter. You can test it out by running a regex with and without |'s and see if the usage of pipes will cause an error. If that is the case then you may have to validate by regex by other means, maybe use a callback function as detailed on this [page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) where your function will do a preg_match using the regex which needs to be inside the function of course and then return true/false.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. Now I'm trying to use a callback, but since my rules are implemented in config/form_validation.php instead of within the same controller, for some reason it's not being called. I've put the callback within the controller, and also tried in its parent controller which is located in the application/core directory. But the callback is not executed.

Comment: Can you post the callback function and code in the question so I can see how it is being done. Also please specify where each is located as in what files and classes.

Comment: remove the exit; and please see if the echo prints out by looking for the output of echo in the page's HTML. Also you should be putting the function in a helper file.

Comment: Big mistake! It was just a misspelling error. I declared the function as mach_date() without the t. The method is finally well placed within the controller class.

Anyway, this is not over. I had to declare it public, so it might be reached from a request URL. I will have to re-route it.

Comment: Anyway placing it inside a helper like you said should work. I didn't figure it out.

Comment: I was wondering why my regex didn't work. I had millions of pipes in it.. now I know why. Thanks!