# Codeigniter's regex match

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation

I have this regular expression for validation in javascript:

```
/^(?:'[A-z](([\._\-][A-z0-9])|[A-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*')$/
```

Now I want the same regular expression for the form validation using Codeigniter's form validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Nombre de usuario', 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[15]|regex_match[/^[A-Z a-z 0-9 _ . \-]+$/]|is_unique[user.username]');
```

the regex in that line is not equivalent to the one I mentioned.

When trying to copy and paste same regex, It doesn't work. I know this is dumb i just can't seem to fully understand regular expressions.

Comment: **Warning:** `[A-z]` is not the same as `[A-Za-z]`.  It also matches several punctuation characters whose code points lie between `Z` and `a`.  It is an error to use the range `A-z` in a character class.

Answer (score 6):

Though there is <s>no</s> [`regex_match()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L909-L917) method in CodeIgniter [validation library](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php), It's not listed in the CI User Guide.

Per [@Limon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689507/limon)'s comment:

> There is a bug in CodeIgniter with the pipe `|`, it breaks the regex.

CodeIgniter [uses `|`](https://github.com/henriqueoliveira/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L341) as a separator between validate methods.

Therefore, to prevent from breaking the regex, you could create a [callback method](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) in your Controller to validate the input by matching the regex:

```php
public function regex_check($str)
{
    if (preg_match("/^(?:'[A-Za-z](([\._\-][A-Za-z0-9])|[A-Za-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*')$/", $str))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('regex_check', 'The %s field is not valid!');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Then add the validation rule, as follows:

```php
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Nombre de usuario', 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[15]|callback_regex_check|is_unique[user.username]');
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. There is a regex_match in codeigniter's form_validation.php. It's this: public function regex_match($str, $regex)
 {
  if ( ! preg_match($regex, $str))
  {
   return FALSE;
  }

  return  TRUE;
 }

Comment: Thanks again. I have found in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804721/regex-match-in-codeigniter-form-validation-generates-message-preg-match-no   that there is a bug in Codeigniter with the pipe, it breaks the regex. Is there a way to make my regex without the pipe | ?

Comment: @Limon Well, CodeIgniter use `|` for separating the validator methods, The only option I could suggest is using callback method.

Comment: Yes it's a solution. But I also think callbacks have to be implemented for more complex functions. In this case I consider there isn't such a complexity so another equivalent regular expression would be better

Comment: @Limon Yes, if the regex could be rewritten in different way.

Answer (score 0):

You might provide rules as an array :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Nombre de usuario', array('required', 'min_length[2]', 'max_length[15]', 'regex_match[/^(?:\'[A-z](([\._\-][A-z0-9])|[A-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*\')$/]', 'is_unique[user.username]'));
```

This way regex with pipes won't crash