# How to validate post value : the first character not allow 1 or 4 in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am validating phone number with codeigniter

In my city, I apply the rule like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('voter_phone', 'Phone number', 'required|exact_length[8]|integer');
```

however, since my city doesn't have the 1 or 4 for the first character , I would like to know are there any way to add checking for this rule? Thanks for helping

Reference:
http://cimple.org/user_guide/libraries/validation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use callback for that purpose its available in the same [LINK](http://cimple.org/user_guide/libraries/validation.html) you have mentioned

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('voter_phone', 'Phone number', 'required|exact_length[8]|integer|callback_valid_number');
```

and callback function can be

```
public function valid_number($str)
{   
    if(!preg_match("/^[235-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$/", $str))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_number', 'Invalid Mobile No.');
        return false;
    }   
    else
    { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

this regex checks if

```
 1. it is required
 2. phone number is int only
 3. it should be exactly 8 digit
 4. it does not start with either 1 or 4
```

so you can remove `required|exact_length[8]|integer`

Comment: nice regex to include all validation. Adding to this, form validation library have built in function for regex check called regex_match. But its not documented. you can see this here http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/195050/

Comment: yeah its there, but there is a bug with `regex + form validation piping` so i usually use callbacks. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439805/codeigniters-regex-match for more info. @MayankTailor

Answer (score 1):

You need a callback to validate your custom validation.

```
//here checkphone is custom callback
$this->form_validation->set_rules('voter_phone', 'Phone number', 'required|exact_length[8]|integer|callback_checkphone');
```

so make a function/method called checkphone in your controller and validate your input(voter_phone)

```
function checkphone($num)
    {
        //your first charcter in voter_phone
        $first_ch = substr($num,0,1);
        if ($first_ch==1 || $first==4)
        {
            //set your error message here
           $this->form_validation->set_message('checkphone','Invalid Phone number,Not allowed 1 or 4 as first charcter');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
            return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: -1...your callback is **checkphone** and you are setting message as `set_message('voter_phone',...` you should check http://cimple.org/user_guide/libraries/validation.html